# C Shared Object Library makefile

Tags: c, makefile, shared-libraries

I am trying to create a makefile that will create a shared library using the my_sin.o, my_cos.o, and my_tan.o files. I was able to create a static version but am having issues with the changes needed for a shared Library.

Currently also getting the following output when I attempt to make. I have verified that everything that should be a tab is.

```
make: Nothing to be done for 'libmy_math.so'.
```

Makefile:

```
CC=gcc

CFLAGS=-fPIC -Wall -g

OBJECTS=my_sin.o my_cos.o my_tan.o

LIBDIR=-L/home/devin/Desktop/CSCV352/Week9/HW_9_5/HW_9_5

libmy_math.so: my_sin.o my_cos.o my_tan.o

test_9_5:$(OBJECTS) main.c libmy_math.so

.c.o:
        $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c $<

clean:
        rm -f *~
        rm -f *.o
        rm -f test_9_5
```

Comment: But where's the rule to build `libmy_math.so`?  I'm not aware of any built-in rule for this.  Also, why is `main.c` a dependency of the target `all`?

Comment: Well, you've created a prerequisite `libmy_math.so` but you haven't defined any rule to actually create it.  You have to tell make how to do that.

Comment: Should it not be a dependency of all? That is how I have had it for other things and it has been working.

Answer (score 0):

The file 'libmy_math.so' doesn't exist yet or the makefile can't find it. If you want 'libmy_math.so' to be created by the makefile, there needs to be a rule where libmy_math.so appears on the left of the colon.

Comment: Sorry, I am really new to makefiles. I conceptually understand what you're saying but am confused about how the rule you are mentioning. I should put it on a line above the "all:" line?

Comment: Generally, you put the name of the file you want to create on the left of the colon, not some random word. So, it'd be like `libmy_math.so: (dependent files)` and the recipe is how to make that file.

For example, in your above post, your rule `all` is making a file called `test_9_5`, right? You could instead change that to `test_9_5: $(OBJECTS) main.c libmy_math.so`.

Comment: not sure which random word you are referring to? from what I understand the OBJECTS line points to the files I want to be included, and the all link lets me include the above statements?

Comment: Okay, so i made some changes and edited it in the main area above. Now it is saying nothing to be done?

Comment: When you type `make`, it only runs the top-most rule. Your top-most rule now does nothing. Perhaps this site is helpful in understanding make?: https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html